# cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close' when using timeoutDialog plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implement a simple session expire bit of code for a server using timeoutDialog plugin. The dialog box appears correctly but on click of any of the buttons I get an error ~`cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'` in `/static/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js line 2 > eval`. Could any one help me please?

Here's my code block:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var timeout = 10000;

    $(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function() {
        // function you want to fire when the user goes idle
        $.timeoutDialog({ timeout: 1,
                          countdown: 10,
                          logout_redirect_url: '/logout/',
                          keep_alive_url:'/',
                          restart_on_yes: true });
        });
        $(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function() {
            // function you want to fire when the user becomes active again
        });
        $.idleTimer(timeout);
    });

    <script src="${request.static_url('static/js/timeout-dialog.js')}"></script>
    <script src="${request.static_url('static/js/idle-timer.js')}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many options. Looks like the timeoutDialog plugin doesn't support later versions of jQuery properly. [Example](http://pure-essence.net/2010/02/14/jquery-session-timeout-countdown/) here solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**
Modify this line in timeout-dialog.js file

```
destroyDialog: function () {
            if ($("#timeout-dialog").length) {
                $("#timeout-dialog").dialog("close");
                $('#timeout-dialog').remove();
            }
        },
```

**